# What is the difference between the Nobel Banquet and the Nobel Anniversary Dinner?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, names

On December 10, 1945, the Nobel Banquet took place in Sweden and the "5th Annual Nobel Anniversary Dinner" took place in New York City.

I understand that the Nobel Prizes are always presented in Sweden and Norway, but I'm confused as to why there was an additional event occurring on the same day.

Comment: The banquet is official, part of the ceremony. Nothing stops winners getting together and celebrate later on, somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The **Nobel Banquet on December 10, 1945** was held by the [Nobel Assembly at the Karolinska Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobel_Assembly_at_the_Karolinska_Institute) which awards Nobel prizes for Physiology or Medicine. The [winners in 1945](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/medicine/1945/summary/) were [Sir Alexander Fleming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Fleming), [Ernst Boris Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chain) and [Sir Howard Walter Florey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Florey). The Nobel Assembly is one of the prize-awarding institutions of the [Nobel Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobel_Foundation).

The other prize-awarding institutions are the [Royal Swedish Academy of Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Swedish_Academy_of_Sciences) (natural sciences and mathematics), the [Swedish Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_Academy) (literature) and the [Norwegian Nobel Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Nobel_Committee) (peace).

---

The **American Nobel Anniversary Committee** was [founded by Albert Einstein](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1988/12/10/beauty-and-the-brains/807f9769-cb94-4aa2-95b6-2e164c578d72/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.55577da0eb8c) and held it's first **dinner** on December 10th in 1941, Dec 10th being the anniversary of Alfred Nobel's death. In addition to remembering Alfred Nobel, it honours past Nobel prize winners. The evening includes a dinner, presentation of past Nobel laureates, and a forum with speeches by some of these former winners as well other notable figures. The committee which organized this annual event has no connection to the [Nobel committees which decide on the prizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobel_Committee) or to the Nobel Foundation.

A [copy of the program for **December 10, 1945** event (the 5th one) held at the Hotel Astor in New York can be seen here](http://credo.library.umass.edu/view/pageturn/mums312-b105-i062/#page/1/mode/1up). It doesn't show what the topic of the forum was but U.S. Secretary of State [Cordell Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordell_Hull) (not present) was honoured for winning the Peace Prize). At the 1944 event the title was [Education for Peace](http://credo.library.umass.edu/view/pageturn/mums312-b104-i529/#page/1/mode/1up) where speakers included five past winners as well as [J. William Fulbright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._William_Fulbright) and 20th Century Fox film studio head [Darryl F. Zanuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darryl_F._Zanuck). By 1958, it appears that the dinner had been moved to January 11th ([a broadcast with Mike Wallace can be seen here](http://www.hrc.utexas.edu/multimedia/video/2008/wallace/nobelprizes.html)).

[image]

*"In this special telecast from the American Nobel Anniversary Committee Dinner and Forum at the Waldorf-Astoria in New York, Dr. Linus Pauling, Pearl S. Buck, Clarence Pickett, and Sir John Boyd Orr talk about peace in a world threatened by war."* [Image and text source](http://www.hrc.utexas.edu/multimedia/video/2008/wallace/nobelprizes.html)

In 1964, an off-shoot of the American Nobel Anniversary Committee, the American Nobel Memorial Foundation, Inc., was [charged with fraud and misrepresentation](https://www.nytimes.com/1964/04/29/archives/charity-defends-its-use-of-nobel-charge-of-fraud-denied-by.html). The Committee appears to keep a low profile these days; it has a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/American-Nobel-Anniversary-Committee/148321848544936) which, bizarrely, has mostly posts of football/soccer players. The committee is based in Wetsport, Connecticut.